# Bluetooth headphones disconnect as soon as I try to use its microphone

Tags: audio, bluetooth, crash, headphones, microphone

Recently, both my Bose QC35 II and AirPods stopped working on my mac.

As soon as I open anything that uses the mic, whatever window that is freezes and then the headphone/airpods disconnect. Even if its just the sound settings.

I already tried removing/adding things again and even reset the bluetooth module. The later seems to have fixed the issue for a while, but it came back after a couple of days.

I looked into `blueetoothd` and `coreaudiod` logs, and all I see when I open the sound settings input/output tabs is errors...

`coreaudiod`:

```
2020-10-06 14:36:48.605171-0300 0x21d2a5   Default     0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (BluetoothAudioPlugIn) Couldn't truncate shared memory: Invalid argument (22). Ignoring error
2020-10-06 14:36:48.721084-0300 0x21d6a7   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DCFString: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:36:48.731267-0300 0x21d6df   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:36:48.732936-0300 0x21d6bd   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:36:48.989497-0300 0x21d6de   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:36:48.990124-0300 0x21d6c5   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:36:49.004676-0300 0x21d740   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:36:49.004877-0300 0x21d6de   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:36:51.985375-0300 0x21d73e   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (BluetoothAudioPlugIn) [com.apple.bluetooth:bluetoothaudiod] Failed to receive incoming SCO data
2020-10-06 14:36:51.985646-0300 0x21d73e   Default     0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  Error during StartHardware call, calling StopHardware(): -536870186
2020-10-06 14:36:51.985814-0300 0x21d6c9   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_IOContext::StartIOThread: the IO thread failed to start, Error: -536870186 (<private>)
2020-10-06 14:36:55.258742-0300 0x21d775   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (BluetoothAudioPlugIn) [com.apple.bluetooth:bluetoothaudiod] Failed to receive incoming SCO data
2020-10-06 14:36:55.259078-0300 0x21d775   Default     0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  Error during StartHardware call, calling StopHardware(): -536870186
2020-10-06 14:36:55.259295-0300 0x21d6d7   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_IOContext::StartIOThread: the IO thread failed to start, Error: -536870186 (<private>)
2020-10-06 14:36:58.536156-0300 0x21d780   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (BluetoothAudioPlugIn) [com.apple.bluetooth:bluetoothaudiod] Failed to receive incoming SCO data
2020-10-06 14:36:58.536471-0300 0x21d780   Default     0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  Error during StartHardware call, calling StopHardware(): -536870186
2020-10-06 14:36:58.536697-0300 0x21d6c9   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_IOContext::StartIOThread: the IO thread failed to start, Error: -536870186 (<private>)
2020-10-06 14:37:00.271641-0300 0x21d7d2   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:00.271857-0300 0x21d7d2   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:00.303441-0300 0x21d7c4   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:00.303640-0300 0x21d7d0   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:14.564078-0300 0x21d9a1   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:14.564365-0300 0x21d9a1   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:14.583956-0300 0x21d9a1   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:14.584163-0300 0x21d9a1   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:14.989580-0300 0x21d7df   Default     0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (BluetoothAudioPlugIn) [com.apple.bluetooth:bluetoothaudiod] XPC Error remove all devices
2020-10-06 14:37:17.572464-0300 0x21d808   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (BluetoothAudioPlugIn) [com.apple.bluetooth:bluetoothaudiod] Failed to receive incoming SCO data
2020-10-06 14:37:17.572903-0300 0x21d808   Default     0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  Error during StartHardware call, calling StopHardware(): -536870186
2020-10-06 14:37:17.573176-0300 0x21d7ba   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_IOContext::StartIOThread: the IO thread failed to start, Error: -536870186 (<private>)
2020-10-06 14:37:17.581020-0300 0x21da06   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:17.581400-0300 0x21da06   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:17.673358-0300 0x21da08   Default     0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (BluetoothAudioPlugIn) [com.apple.bluetooth:bluetoothaudiod] XPC Error remove all devices
2020-10-06 14:37:17.701881-0300 0x21d9e8   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DCFString: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:17.703955-0300 0x21d9e8   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:17.704334-0300 0x21d9e8   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_Object_GetPropertyData_DAI32: the object does not implement the property
2020-10-06 14:37:17.825617-0300 0x21d7ba   Error       0x0                  60109  0    coreaudiod: (CoreAudio)  HALS_IOContext::StartIOThread: no master engine info
```

`bluetootdhd`:

```
2020-10-06 14:36:43.105800-0300 0x21cb0a   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:43.121454-0300 0x21cb0a   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:43.134401-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 12 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:43.134522-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 10 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:43.134634-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 16 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:45.074236-0300 0x21cb0a   Error       0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] CoreBluetooth isn't advertising for client type 9
2020-10-06 14:36:45.109313-0300 0x21d226   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:45.130499-0300 0x21cb0a   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:45.130701-0300 0x21cb0a   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:45.144810-0300 0x21d226   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 12 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:45.144951-0300 0x21d226   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 16 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:45.159886-0300 0x21cb0a   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:45.173837-0300 0x21cb0a   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 12 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:45.173976-0300 0x21cb0a   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 16 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:47.990444-0300 0x33d      Error       0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (IOBluetooth) [com.apple.bluetooth:CBPipeManager] peer doesn't exsit
2020-10-06 14:36:58.097613-0300 0x21d226   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:58.112840-0300 0x21d226   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:58.131875-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 12 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:58.131971-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 10 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:36:58.132048-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 16 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:00.074386-0300 0x21d226   Error       0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] CoreBluetooth isn't advertising for client type 9
2020-10-06 14:37:00.119676-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:00.150945-0300 0x21d226   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:00.151135-0300 0x21d226   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:00.166202-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 12 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:00.166335-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 16 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:00.180246-0300 0x21d226   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:00.193055-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 12 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:00.193132-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 16 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:13.100181-0300 0x21d226   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:13.115566-0300 0x21d790   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:13.132187-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 12 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:13.132337-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 10 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:13.132449-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 16 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:15.074077-0300 0x21d28b   Error       0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] CoreBluetooth isn't advertising for client type 9
2020-10-06 14:37:15.116296-0300 0x21d226   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:15.140577-0300 0x21d226   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:15.140947-0300 0x21d226   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:15.153948-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 12 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:15.154062-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 16 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:15.170015-0300 0x21d790   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] [Privacy] Did stop advertising with error: (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:15.183120-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 12 with error (null)
2020-10-06 14:37:15.183208-0300 0x21d28b   Default     0x0                  153    0    bluetoothd: (WPDaemon) [com.apple.bluetooth:WirelessProximity] Started to advertise for type 16 with error (null)
```

I don't know what's happening nor how to fix it... does anyone knows what those errors mean, if they are expected and what can I do to resolve them?

Comment: You may have an issue with the Bluetooth module on your Mac.  The first thing to do is verify that that the headphones work with other devices (another Mac, an iPhone, etc.) with no problem.  Also try booting in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting) to see if the problem persists.  This will help narrow things down for a more accurate diagnosis.

Comment: Yeah both the headphones and the airpods work as expected on other devices, e.g. my iPhone... I'm pretty sure its something on the mac, not sure what though...